# How to check if a List of dict items is subset or equal to another list with dict items

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose,

```
d1 = [{'id':'112','type':'address0'}, {'id':'113', 'type':'address0'}]  
d2 = [{'id':'112','type':'address0'}, {'id':'113', 'type':'address0'},{'id':'114', 'type':'address0'}] 
d3 = [{'id':'111','type':'address0'}, {'id':'113', 'type':'address0'}]   
d4 = [{'id':'112','type':'address0'}, {'id':'113', 'type':'address0'}]
```

Test results:

```
test_subset(d1,d2) # True
test_subset(d3,d2) # False
test_subset(d1,d4) # True
```

When tried with `set(d1).issubset(d2)`, script error is seen.

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Note: Here the each of lists are lines captured from two large files for comparing line by line so that only unique lines from both files are saved

Comment: Do you need to compare more than just the `id`?

Comment: No, "type" value also needs be considered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn each inner dict to a set of tuples and then perform a simple `set` subset check.

Thanks to @AChampion for the simplification.

```
def _to_set(d):
    return {(V['id'], V['type']) for V in d}

def test_subset(d1, d2):
    return set.issubset(*map(_to_set, [d1, d2]))
```

```
test_subset(d1,d2)
True

test_subset(d3,d2)
False

test_subset(d1,d4)
True
```

For a more generalised solution when you have more than two key-value pairs to consider, consider building a frozenset instead:

```
def _to_set(d):
    return {frozenset(tuple(v) for v in V.items()) for V in d}
```

The rest remains the same.

Comment: Can you guarantee that `id` and `value` will always come out in the same order with `V.items()` in Py2.7? Alternatively `{(V['id'], V['value']) for V in d}` would work.

Comment: @AChampion Hmm, are we not guaranteed tuples of (k : v) pairs in python2 with dict.items? Or maybe I've misunderstood.

Comment: Yes, ignore - I was thinking strictly `tuples`